# What is the difference between hidden states and mixture components in a continuous Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: machine-learning, stochastic-processes, markov-process, gaussian-mixture-distribution, hidden-markov-model

I'm trying to understand how a continuous Hidden Markov Model works and I am confused by the difference of the hidden states of the discrete latent variables and the mixture components in the emission probabilities. Initially, I was under the impression that the hidden states of the discrete variable corresponds to the mixture components of the Gaussian mixture but I discovered that this is wrong. I thought that when we transition from state i to state j, we move from mixture component i to mixture component j.

An explanation of their difference as well as how they are related would be highly appreciated. Moreover, given an observation sequence and suppose that we want to learn the parameters of the CHMM, how can we determine how many states and how many mixture components there are.

Any help would be very much appreciated.